# Das Keyboard Ultimate Model S Silent: is it really silent? Blank keys are problematic or not?

Tags: keyboard

Das Keyboard Ultimate Model S Silent: is it really silent? Does it stay that silent in the long run (*all* the keyboards I know don't)?

Blank keys are a problem or not? I.e. do we get used to them or do we endlessly find the "right" key to type the ', the { and the } (I'm talking as a developper (C/Php/Delphi))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blank keys are no problem for a *true* touch-typist. If you want to try out whether you'll have big issues, try programming in the complete dark and see how much you have to search for the keys. This is a very personal issue; I personally don't have an issue with blank keys, but most people having to use my blank keyboard do find it difficult.

As for the DAS Keyboard, I don't have experience with this exact model, but due to the high build quality and the use of true mechanical switches with damping, it *should* remain completely quiet for its lifetime. Just remember that only diamonds are forever.

Keep us updated if you do end up purchasing this model!

Comment: Maybe for Christmas. Thanks for the tip I'll test my keyboard in the dark!

Comment: In case you have issues with typing in the dark, or have trouble with specific keys and are still set on getting this keyboard, there are companies that will sell "key-covers" which cover up the keys on your current keyboard and allow you to practice typing on a "blank" keyboard. Look around, they are simply plastic covers meant for schools to teach kids to type, but come handy for anyone looking to better their blind typing.

Comment: I'm a TRUE touch typist... when it's about writing letters or English (like I'm currently doing), but when it comes to programming, it's another plafield, and spécial characters are never easy to reach (especially on this god d*mn stupid French AZERTY layout ('{' => alt gr 4, '}' => alt gr =, '[' = alt gr 5 and so on, even '<' and '>' are on the same key : '<' without shift and '>' with shift))... thanks again for the answer.

Comment: I touch type, but I would never consider a blank keyboard as trying to find special characters would drive me nuts.

Comment: Surely the key covers would have to fit on the keys, and getting a perfect fit would be unlikely?  Pieces of black insulation tape would work well as an alternative, of you want that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

The keyboard is most certainly not Silent. The "Silent" specification refers to the type of mechanical keyswitches it uses which are quieter than those used in the standard Das Keyboard.

If you compare the two side by side, the normal model will have the noticeable click of its keyswitches, while the Silent model will have more "normal" keyboard noise.

You could always purchase the non-blank-keycapped version.

Comment: I have had several Cherry keyboards.  I would guess that the normal Das Keyboard has the 'blue' MX switches, while the quite ones have 'brown'.  There are also 'black', 'clear', 'red' and 'white', IIRC, with different combinations of clickiness and resistance force.  Even the ones without the click sound are very loud compared to cheap membrane keyboards, as the click is only a small part of the noise made when you are banging away.

Comment: And here is how 'silent' the silent version is!  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFsVGyCcMpA&feature=related

Comment: I meant 'quiet', not 'quite', earlier.  <cringe>

Answer (score 2):

I've finally decided to buy it.
See [Olivier Pons DAS Keyboard](http://olivierpons.fr/2011/04/20/das-keyboard-je-lai-enfin-recu/) (it's French).
As for the noise, you're right: it's very noisy. I can barely imagine how noisy the Cherry MX blue are!
(I'm typing with it actually). Like I said in French: it's very strange because it's noisy but the feeling you get when you type is way way better than with the classical keyboards.
The only problem concerns developing: accessing special keys is harder with blank keys. Nevertheless I'm often switching between my Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000 (the only keyboard that stayed quiet after years of use (and I've bought more than 20 keyboards including the Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 which became very noisy after ~6 months)) and my DAS Keyboard.

Conclusion:

The pleasure I get when I type is kind of hard to explain but it's definitely more pleasant to use my DAS when I'm *not* developing, than any other keyboard.